# Can't show data in group tableview in xcode5

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios7, uitableview, xcode5.0.1

I am new to xcode5. And i used to group tableview in my app. it's work fine in iOS6.1 but doesn't show data in iOS7. It is just display "Header" section.
That is my code :

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [atableView reloadData];

    self.notification = [[UISwitch alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    LoginSetting = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Company ID",@"Username",nil];
    [LoginSetting retain];
    mic = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Notification",@"App Version",@"Server",nil];
    [mic retain];

    detailText=[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"kaisquare",@"admin",nil];
    [detailText retain];

    logout=[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"",nil];
    self.title = @"Setting";
}
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 3;
}
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if(section == 0)
        return [LoginSetting count];
    else if(section==1)
        return [mic count];
    else
        return [logout count];
}
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if(section == 0)
        return @"Login Setting";
    else if(section==1)
        return @"Mics";
    else
        return @"";
}
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if(indexPath.section == 0)
    {
        if (indexPath.row == 0)
        {

        }
        else if (indexPath.row == 1)
        {

        }
        else
        {

        }
    }
    else if(indexPath.section==1)
    {
        if (indexPath.row == 0)
        {

        }
        else if (indexPath.row == 1)
        {
        }
        else if (indexPath.row == 2)
        {

            alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Server" message:@"" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"Okay", nil];
            alertView.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput;
            myTextField = [alertView textFieldAtIndex:0];
            myTextField.text=mainString;
            [alertView show];
            [alertView release];
        }
        else
        {

        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (indexPath.row == 0)
        {
        }
    }

}
-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView
didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{

    if (buttonIndex != 1)
    {
        NSLog(@"Cancel");
        return;
    }
    else
    {

    }
}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView
                              dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier
                              forIndexPath:indexPath];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
       // cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault                                      reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

        cellCompanyId = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(-20, 0, cell.frame.size.width, cell.frame.size.height)];
        cellCompanyId.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        cellCompanyId.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:18];
        cellCompanyId.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
        [cell addSubview:cellCompanyId];

        cellUsername = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(-20, 0, cell.frame.size.width, cell.frame.size.height)];
        cellUsername.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        cellUsername.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:18];
        cellUsername.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
        [cell addSubview:cellUsername];

        cellAppversion = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(-20, 0, cell.frame.size.width, cell.frame.size.height)];
        cellAppversion.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        cellAppversion.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:18];
        cellAppversion.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
        [cell addSubview:cellAppversion];

        cellServer = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(-20, 0, cell.frame.size.width, cell.frame.size.height)];
        cellServer.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        cellServer.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14];
        cellServer.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
        [cell addSubview:cellServer];
    }
    // Set up the cell...
    if(indexPath.section == 0)
    {
        cell.textLabel.text = [LoginSetting objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        if (indexPath.row == 0)
        {
            cellCompanyId.textAlignment=NSTextAlignmentRight;
            cellCompanyId.text = strCompanyid;
        }
        else if (indexPath.row == 1)
        {
            cellUsername.textAlignment=NSTextAlignmentRight;
            cellUsername.text = strUsertxt;
        }
        else
            return 0;
    }
    else if(indexPath.section==1)
    {
        cell.textLabel.text = [mic objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        if (indexPath.row == 0)
        {
            UISwitch *aSwitch = [[[UISwitch alloc]init]autorelease];
            aSwitch.frame=CGRectMake(215, 7, 0, 0);
           [aSwitch addTarget:self action:@selector(switchChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
            [cell.contentView addSubview:aSwitch];
        }
        else if (indexPath.row == 1)
        {
            cellAppversion.textAlignment=NSTextAlignmentRight;
            cellAppversion.text = @"1.3.1";
        }
        else if (indexPath.row == 2)
        {
            cellServer.textAlignment=NSTextAlignmentRight;
            cellServer.text = mainString;
        }
        else
            return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        if (indexPath.row == 0)
        {
            UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
            [button addTarget:self
                      action:@selector(LogoutEvent)
             forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
            UIImage *buttonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"login_button.png"];
            [button setBackgroundImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            button.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, cell.frame.size.width, cell.frame.size.height);
            [cell addSubview:button];
        }
    }
    //UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark
    return cell;
}
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 35.0;
}
```

I don't understand why my tableViews is shown in xcode4, and xcode5 one isn't. I'm using Dynamic Prototype Content Grouped Style UITableView.

Comment: use [cell.contentView addSubview:cellCompanyId]; instead of [cell addSubview:cellCompanyId]; Add all subviews of cell to contentView.

Comment: I don't understend why you need `if (cell == nil){...}` statement. `[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath]` never returns nil.

Comment: @Savitha thank you, But it does not work :(

Answer (score 0):

You must register a class or nib file using the `registerNib:forCellReuseIdentifier:` or `registerClass:forCellReuseIdentifier:` method before calling `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:` method.